# Parse api response to store results in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, api, response

I do an api call as below and get the response in the specified format. have a list in the below format.
Type of response is str. Wondering is there a way to parse the response and append it to a dataframe.
Not sure how this could be done as the response type is "string".
Any suggestions would be appreciated

```
API call:
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload,verify=False)
result = response.text


Response:
[{"id":"123",
  "addr1":"55 West",
  "addr2":"",
  "city":"Burl",
  "province":"ON",
  "postal_code":"ABCDEF",
  "vendor_number":"asdkfhka"},
  {"id":"345",
   "addr1":"55 East",
   "addr2":"",
   "city":"Burl",
   "province":"ON",
   "postal_code":"ABCDEF",
   "vendor_number":"asdk"}]
```

Resultant dataframe has to be of format:

```
   id   addr1   addr2   city   province    postal_code    vendor_number
   123  55 West         Burl   ON          ABCDEF         asdkfhka
   345  55 East         Burl   ON          ABCDEF         asdk
```

Comment: @not_speshal: yes, thanks. corrected it

Answer (score 2):

You have a `json` string. Try:

```
import json
df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(Response))

>>> df
    id    addr1 addr2  city province postal_code vendor_number
0  123  55 West        Burl       ON      ABCDEF      asdkfhka
1  345  55 East        Burl       ON      ABCDEF          asdk
```